# with already added an item with the same key TREEVIEW vb.net and sql server

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this error, and I'm not sure what's causing it:

> an element with the same key has already been added

I am showing data in a treeview as follows: DEPARTMENT / PROVINCE / DISTRICT attachment code made in visual basic:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conexaoSQLServer As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet


    Dim strCon As String = "Data Source = SOPORTE-ERP\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = prueba; Integrated Security = True"
        'define a consulta para obter as tabelas e suas colunas
    Dim sqlConsulta As String = "SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,''AS nodeParentKey FROM DEPARTAMENTO " +
        "UNION ALL SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey " +
        "FROM PROVINCIAS UNION SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DIST' + CAST(IDUBIGEO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey," +
         "'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM UBIGEO"


    Try
        'define e abre a conexão com o SQL Server
        conexaoSQLServer = New SqlConnection(strCon)
        conexaoSQLServer.Open()

        'atribui o comando usado na conexão
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlConsulta, conexaoSQLServer)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        'preenche o dataset
        da.Fill(ds, "DATOS_SISTEMAS")

        'Helper dictionaries
        Dim nodes2 As New Dictionary(Of String, TreeNode) 'Holds the nodes based on their key values
        Dim nodeParents As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'Holds the parent keys of child nodes

        'Create nodes from data
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("DATOS_SISTEMAS").Rows
            Dim nodeText2 As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeText")
            Dim nodeKey2 As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeKey")
            Dim nodeParentKey2 As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeParentKey")

            nodes2.Add(nodeKey2, New TreeNode(nodeText2))

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeParentKey2) Then
                nodeParents.Add(nodeKey2, nodeParentKey2)
            End If
        Next

        'Add nodes to treeview (and resolve parents)
        For Each kvp In nodes2
            Dim node1 As TreeNode = kvp.Value
            Dim nodeKeys1 As String = kvp.Key
            Dim nodeParentKeys1 As String = Nothing

            If nodeParents.TryGetValue(nodeKeys1, nodeParentKeys1) Then
                'Child node
                Dim parentNode As TreeNode = nodes2(nodeParentKeys1)
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(node1)
            Else
                'Root node
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node1)

            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error when performing this operation:  " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    Finally
       'libera os recursos da conexão usada
        conexaoSQLServer.Close()
        conexaoSQLServer.Dispose()
        conexaoSQLServer = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

I validated that the ID fields of each table are unique and autoincrementing. It seems to be an error with the dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Calling `.Close()`, `.Dispose()`, and setting to `Nothing` is hold-over from the vb6/vbscript era, and is no longer needed or helpful, and can in rare cases be actively harmful. `.Dispose()` alone is enough for VB.Net

Comment: Assuming you have stepped through your code and looked at the errant values at a breakpoint or error, what are the problematic values and on which line does the error occur? `nodes2.Add(nodeKey2, New TreeNode(nodeText2))
`? `parentNode.Nodes.Add(node1)`? More detailed info please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect missing a `Tree1.Nodes.Clear()` is the main problem, but there may be other things as well, the question is missing some important info (data!), and the code is written in an outdated style. The result is I had to modernize as I went to find even this much, and I may still be missing something. See below, and take note of the commends I added:

```vb
'Separate DB access from event code!
Friend Module DB
    Private connectString As String = "Data Source = SOPORTE-ERP\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = prueba; Integrated Security = True"

    Public Function GetTreeNodeData() As DataTable
        'multi-line string literals work now
        Dim sql As String = "
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,''AS nodeParentKey 
    FROM DEPARTAMENTO
UNION ALL 
    SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey
    FROM PROVINCIAS 
UNION 
    SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DIST' + CAST(IDUBIGEO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey 
    FROM UBIGEO
) t
ORDER BY t.NodeParentKey, t.NodeKey, t.NodeText"

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectString), _
              cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn), _
              da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            'preenche o dataset
            da.Fill(ds, "DATOS_SISTEMAS") '.Fill() opens and closes automatically
        End Using 'End Using closes the connection, **even if an exception is thrown!**
        Return ds.Tables("DATOS_SISTEMAS")
    End Function
End Module


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click   
    'Limit the scope of each try/catch, so the error message can be more meaningful/helpful
    Dim nodeRecords As DataTable
    Try
        'Create nodes from data
        nodeRecords = DB.GetTreeNodeData()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show($"Error performing database operation:{vbCrLf}{ex.Message}")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim nodes As New Dictionary(Of String, TreeNode)
    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In nodeRecords.Rows
            Dim nodeKey As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeKey")
            Dim nodeText As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeText")
            Dim parentKey As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeParentKey")

            If Not nodes.ContainsKey(parentKey) Then
                nodes.Add(parentKey, new TreeNode())
            End If

            If nodes.ContainsKey(nodeKey) Then
                nodes(nodeKey).Text = nodeText
                nodes(parentKey).Nodes.Add(nodes(nodeKey)) 'we know the parent exists, because we just created it if it was missing               
            Else
                Dim node As New TreeNode(nodeText)
                nodes(parentKey).Nodes.Add(node)
                nodes.Add(nodeKey, node)
            End If

        Next row
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show($"Error building tree:{vbCrLf}{ex.Message}")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    TreeView1.SuspendLayout() 'suspend/resume layout avoids flickering as control is updated
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear() 'I suspect missing this is your main problem
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, TreeNode) In nodes.Where(Function (n) n.Parent Is Nothing)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node1)
    Next kvp
    TreeView1.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello dear, I have 2 errors in this line: nodes (nodeKey) .Parent = nodes (parentKey) ----- tells me that "The Parent property is ReadOnly" and the other is in this part: In nodes.Where (Function (n) n. Parent is nothing) - Overload resolution error because none of the 'Where' functions

Comment: For the 2nd, make sure you have an `Imports System.Linq` at the top.

Comment: Okay, updated to fix the 1st issue as well.